# How to disable a datepicker based on condition

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to disable a datepicker based on a condition using disabled attribute. Please guide me on how can i implement it.

HTML

```
<button (click)="disabled()">test</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" [nbDatepicker]="from"  [readonly]="isDisabled" [attr.disabled]="isDisabled" formControlName="from">
            <nb-datepicker #from></nb-datepicker>
```

TS

```
disabled() {
this.isDisabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `disabled` attribute on your input field without setting any value or anything else it will be disabled.
Easy way to solve your problem is to do:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isDisabled">
<input disabled type="text" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" [nbDatepicker]="from"  [attr.disabled]="isDisabled" formControlName="from">
            <nb-datepicker #from></nb-datepicker>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="!isDisabled">
<input type="text" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" [nbDatepicker]="from" [attr.disabled]="isDisabled" formControlName="from">
            <nb-datepicker #from></nb-datepicker>
</ng-container>
```